# ValueCangeListener work on second try in JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf-2

I have two selectOneMenu elements which their id's make difference only.
 valueChangeListener works on second try.
At first try, page is refreshing, but does not go the valueChangeCode, thefore no value changes. At second try it goes  valueChangeCode and it gets new value and both of selectOneMenu show new value.

```
            <h:selectOneMenu id="changeCurrency" value="#dataBean.showCurrency}"                valueChangeListener="#myBean.changePaymentCurreny}"
valueChangeListener="#{myBean.changePaymentCurreny}"
                immediate="true"
                onchange="submit()">
                <f:selectItems value="#{my.currencyList}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
           <h:selectOneMenu id="changeCurrency2" 
                value="#{dateBean.showCurrency}" 
                valueChangeListener="#{myBean.changePaymentCurreny}"
                immediate="true"
                onchange="submit()">
                <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.currencyList}" />
          </h:selectOneMenu>
```

In ValueChangeListener code.

```
dataBean.setShowCurrency(newCurrency);
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getChildren().clear();
```

When i remove the line which ends with getChidren.clear, and i change value of one them, changeListener called and changes the value at first try.
On view, only one selectmenu which i changed, shows new value. Other selectOnemenu still show the old value.

dataBean and myBean are in sessionScope. When i myBean put on requestscope, ajax request which works on page load, does not cath the mybean cause of being null.

Could anyone make clear this station.
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

try change the valueChangeListener for an ajax event tag like this.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="changeCurrency" value="#dataBean.showCurrency}" valueChangeListener="#myBean.changePaymentCurreny}" onchange="submit()"> 
   <f:selectItems value="#{my.currencyList}" />
   <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{myBean.changePaymentCurreny}" process="@this" partialSubmit="true"  />    
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:selectOneMenu id="changeCurrency2" value="#{dateBean.showCurrency}" onchange="submit()">
   <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.currencyList}" />
   <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{myBean.changePaymentCurreny}" process="@this" partialSubmit="true"  />  
</h:selectOneMenu>
```